# AngularJS simple image preview on file input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can someone tell me why this code does not work?
this my preview area: 
`<div class="preview"><img src="" alt=""></div>`
and this my `input`:
`<input type="file" file-input>`
 and follow my directive code:

```
    var cmos = angular.module('cmos', ['simditor']);
    // controller
    cmos.controller('cmosCtrl', function( $scope ){}
    // directive
    cmos.directive("fileInput", function( $parse ){
            return{
                link: function($scope, element, attrs){
                    element.on('change', function(event){
                        var files = event.target.files;             

                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        var img = document.querySelector(".preview > img");
                        reader.addEventListener("load", function(){
                            img.src = reader.result;
                        }, false);

                        if(files){
                            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);                 
                        }
                        // console.log(files[0]);
                    });
                }
            }   
    });
```

When I insert an image on `input` would like to take an image and show it to preview area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use $scope like this..

```
<div class="preview"><img src="{{imageUrl}}" alt=""></div>
```

and in js.

```
var files = event.target.files;
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.addEventListener("load", function(){
                        $scope.imageUrl = reader.result;
                    }, false);

                    if(files){
                        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);                 
                    }
```